# Restrict permissons when app is in background

Tags: permissions, privacy, background-process

Is there any app, tool, ROM, etc. for Android that lets you restrict selected individual permissions of an app, ONLY when it is in the background?

This should function similarly to the "Restrict background data" feature that help reduce mobile data usage by preventing background apps from using network resources.

For example, you may want an app to have access to your location when you're actively using it, but you don't want it to keep the GPS on in the background, either because it drains the battery and/or is tracking your movements.

Same thing with other permissions like accessing the microphone and camera; because it is very rare for most people to intentionally record audio/video/photos from a background app. Other examples are: send SMS, reading/modifying contacts, write to internal/external storage.

Comment: With just a few improvements, this will be a good question to post on the Software Recommendations SE.

Comment: While off-topic on this site, I quite like the question in itself. Upvoted.

Comment: I think it should be fine for this site. It's not a list question or "what is the best app". The user's looking to achieve a specific goal and explicitly says the answer doesn't have to be an app.

Comment: Your device needs to be rooted to modify permissions. XPrivacy and App ops Xposed module are good for this but both lack (AFAIK) any plugins​ for automation. When the app is in background, limited actions like kill data, location accuracy changes (off/ high accuracy/battery saving/ device only) are possible using Macrodroid Automation app

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't rooted yet, go to your sercurity and see the permissions 
If you have rooted, just use Rom toolbox

Answer (score 0):

My way of getting around the problem is as easy as it gets, because there is no requirement of any kind of rooting or installing a custom ROM. All you have to do is:

1. Open Settings/About Phone;
2. Then click on build version until you become a developer.
3. Now, Open Settings/Developer Options;
4. Scroll down until you find background processes limit - set it to disable background processes.

This should do the trick!